# Software rendering points: Camera matrix, and combining translate/rotate/scale

Tags: javascript, matrix, 3d

For years I used sin/cos to rotate points, not realising that by using a matrix, I could use the same calculated vales applied to every point that shared a common rotation. So I made some JavaScript graphics programs using my newly found (to me) rotation matrix. The results where impressive.

The code below is part of a little class that sets up the rotation matrix, and there's a function just after that applies that matrix to a 3D point.

Below that I include the "projection" code I'm using.

1: I've been reading that it may be possible to do rotation/scaling/translation in ONE matrix!? After looking for awhile, I've yet to find something I understand enough to edit the code that makes my matrix below.

2: I read about a camera matrix a long time ago, but now I realise it is perhaps similar to the rotation matrix? Do all the hard and slow calculations first, and then apply those results to all the thousands of points - resulting in plot-ready 2D screen co-ordinates.

Are those two questions possible in the way I'm doing it for the "simple" rotation code?

I might be sad, but I find the idea of throwing a "3D Camera matrix" at a lot of 3D points to get a sollection of perspective correct 2D points to be very exciting! Lots of my old demos can be speeded up, and have an interesting camera movement around them.

Thanks for all your help  in advance!

https://codepen.io/SarahC/pen/xPGKWK?editors=0010

```
matrixRotate.prototype.makeMatrix = function(x, y, z){
  this.cosa = Math.cos(z * this.radmod);
  this.sina = Math.sin(z * this.radmod);

  this.cosb = Math.cos(y * this.radmod);
  this.sinb = Math.sin(y * this.radmod);

  this.cosc = Math.cos(x * this.radmod);
  this.sinc = Math.sin(x * this.radmod);

  this.Axx = this.cosa * this.cosb;
  this.Axy = this.cosa * this.sinb * this.sinc - this.sina * this.cosc;
  this.Axz = this.cosa * this.sinb * this.cosc + this.sina * this.sinc;

  this.Ayx = this.sina * this.cosb;
  this.Ayy = this.sina * this.sinb * this.sinc + this.cosa * this.cosc;
  this.Ayz = this.sina * this.sinb * this.cosc - this.cosa * this.sinc;

  this.Azx = -this.sinb;
  this.Azy = this.cosb * this.sinc;
  this.Azz = this.cosb * this.cosc;
}

matrixRotate.prototype.rotate = function(x, y, z){
  return {x: this.Axx * x + this.Axy * y + this.Axz * z,
          y: this.Ayx * x + this.Ayy * y + this.Ayz * z,
          z: this.Azx * x + this.Azy * y + this.Azz * z}
}
.
.
.
.
//Scale point for screen.
if (b.rotatedPoint.z < focalLength) {
    b.scale = focalLength / (focalLength - b.rotatedPoint.z);
    b.x = vanishingPoint.x + b.rotatedPoint.x * b.scale;
    b.y = vanishingPoint.y + b.rotatedPoint.y * b.scale;
    b.visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes (and also "skew") -- only that for `D` dimensional space a `(D+1) x (D+1)` matrix is required to include translations (since it is no longer a "linear transformation").
2. There are two components to the "camera matrix":

   - View matrix `V` - this is the inverse of the camera's world space transformation matrix; many 3D math libraries provide a function called `lookAt` which computes this.
   - Projection matrix `P` - this does the perspective transformation. Well, most of it; a *perspective divide* is still required after the transformation, which then gives XY in *normalized device coordinates* (range is [-1.0, 1.0] or [0.0, 1.0] depending on the convention).

   The order of multiplication is `P * V * M` where `M` is the model matrix (the transformation applied to scene geometry). A mnemonic for this is `MVP`, in the order of action on a point.

Countless many resources on the internet; in fact a short section on matrix/vector algebra is almost always the first chapter of any game/graphics programming book.